# Networx showing excessive download bandwidth usage

Tags: bandwidth, monitoring, report

I have only one download started with latest release of Firefox with Windows 7. Firefox shows it is downloading at 180 KB/sec.

Networx shows between 368 KB/sec upload and 1-8 MB/sec download. It is a tv episode that's 458 MB in total that I downloaded in about 40 minutes yet Networx shows me that a total of 11 GB was downloaded in the same time.

This has been the case for sometime, I'm on a limited account of 15 GB a month.

I used SeriousBit NetBalancer to see which programs are using bandwidth and just Firefox shows as the program that's downloading at the mentioned speed.

Connected wireless to router/modem, it has no other user and password protected. Any downloads either from torrents, file host or direct from websites has this same excessive unexplained incoming bandwidth report.

I have done a virus scan and one new threat was found!

> C:\Users\roper\AppData\Local\FilesFrog Update Checker\update_checker.exe-Win32omoto-J [PUP]

An older scan found the following:

> C:\Users\roper\AppData\Local\Temp\7zOB4FF.tmp\Youwave.Android.v2.x.x.Generic.patch-RES.exe-Win32: Malware-gen.

I have been checking out Youwave and Bluestacks Android for PC, but they were uninstalled about a week ago cause I was figuring they had something to do with the problem. After uninstalling the problem still exists, so that is not the cause.

Networx also shows more data used per day than compared to Bells data usage report. Even comparing the amount of data Networx shows vs. Space used on C:\ drive doesn't add the same.

Uninstalled/re-installed Networx. Started a 111 Mb download from Download.am through Firefox. Viewed a comparison between the data usage and bandwidth speed that each displayed.

Firefox DL speed was 80 KB/sec and Networx DL speed was 10 MB/sec averaged. The DL took 45 minutes to complete. Amount of recorded data downloaded in Firefox was 111 Mb and Networx total in that time was 11 GB.

12 services running on the net with Firefox showing the highest use and a trickle of a few bytes here and there from the other services. Haven't seen yet a 11 GB download from that time on Bells Detailed Usage window.

Opened Networx Settings->Monitored interface->checked Ignore local traffic within the LAN option. 
Started a download and viewed if there was a change in Networx bandwidth usage and speed report. Well their isn't the excessive bandwidth usage, more in par with what I'm using for bandwidth with Bell Usage details.

Comment: is this a torrent? is the computer in question actually using the wifi or connected via ethernet cable? Is it wireless n, g..?

Comment: Thank you  horatio, Ive added new info to question. Connected wireless to router/modem.

Comment: If you can, I would review the amount of data that is being reported as downloaded against what your ISP has recorded.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Michael Frank.Networx shows more data used per day then compared to Bells data usage report.

Comment: How much does Bells usage report show? Have you tried any other bandwidth monitors?

Comment: Re-installed Networx. Started a 111mb download from Download.am through Firefox. Opened the "Show all Downloads" window in Firefox and the "Speed Meter (All Connections)" window in Networxs to view a comparison between the data usage and bandwidth speed that each displayed. Firefox DL speed was 80 KB/sec and Networx DL speed was 10 MB/sec average. The DL took 45 minutes to complete. Amount of recorded data downloaded in Firefox was 111 Mb and Networx total in that time was 11 GB.

Comment: 12 services running on the net with Firefox showing the highest use and a trickle of a few bytes here and there from the other services. Haven't seen yet a 11 GB download from that time on Bells Detailed Usage  window.

Comment: Using NetBalancer 7.11 by SeriousBit as-well Mokubai. Its DL usage report seems more realistic.

Comment: I need to ask you a doubt. I also downloaded NetWorx and I installed it. When it was launched it ask for connection name and a password. I don't know what to enter in the password field. The connection is set as localhost. Did you configure NetWorx ? If yes how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Networkx, make sure you are selecting the correct network adapter to monitor. Moreover, if you are monitoring WiFi and happen to copy files from another PC connected to the same WiFi, it will still show up in Networkx. Keep that in mind.

And ISP data is most reliable simply because that's what you are charged for!

Comment: Selected to ignore local traffic in Networx options. Usage makes more sense, thanks tumchaaditya.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 8, which I am guessing you are, you can right click your network and set it to be a metered connection: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/metered-internet-connections-frequently-asked-questions

Furthermore, I think you mean outgoing bandwidth as you say `11gb was downloaded in the same time`

So if you are using a home router, make sure to password protect it. Otherwise neighbors or passer-byers will just use your internet and use up your data.

Comment: Thank you falconspy for your answer . Ive edited the question further

Comment: For grins and giggles, perform an antivirus / antimalware scan on your computer. It is possible it is infected and someone is upload files to your computer if it was actually hijacked. I can't really provide any other feed back unless you include screenshots and more context.

Comment: Wont be able to add images since I don't have 10 rep points

Comment: So one new virus contained and having l look at the comparison between Networx and Bells Bandwidth usage the problem a

Comment: -excuse me-; may be either one of the twos data report. Since a ISP for sure would have the accurate account of the total usage, Ill uninstall/re-install Networx and see if theirs a change in the difference between the amount of data recorded when downloading a file.